# What is a good fabric to protect forearms in 30+°C weather on long rides (in lieu of reapplying high-SPF creams)?

Tags: sun-protection

One way to get faster, it seems, is to leave the city cycling paths (which are often shaded by trees) and to head to long stretches on country roads.

On 4+ hour rides my arms get scorched from the sun, and it's cumulative. This is the case despite applying a famous-brand high-SPF sport-specific cream at the start. Reapplying every hour or two is not a great solution. It seems better to cover up.

Many "arm warmers" in the form of sleeves are available on the market, and these could potentially be used even in 30-35°C weather, subject to drinking a bit more along the ride, but the overheating would be unpleasant.

The very seasoned (from their looks they seem to spend entire days riding) cyclists that I encounter have almost always covered forearms, sometimes with what looks like a material that sits just a few millimeters from the skin—one with ventilation holes. Rather than make a U-turn and ask them, I thought I'd ask here.

What is a good fabric to protect forearms in 30+°C weather?

**Companion question**: Vuelta a España, Tour de France, and Giro d'Italia take place in the height of summer, and the very many competitors ride far longer and in arbitrary weather. Yet they don't seem to bake their skin from the sun, and they certainly neither stop to reapply creams nor wear arm covers. What solution do they use?

Related:

- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/76590/48599

Comment: Most pro cyclists have some tan. Hence why they don’t have to stop to re-apply sun screen. I’m an average white European person and after a week of summer bike touring I have enough tan to only need some cheap SPF20 sun screen in the morning for a whole day in the sun.

Comment: @Michael tan is only another factor of about 2-4 though.  It is even, and a good baseline, though if you switch to shorter shorts or shorter sleeved jerseys late in summer you can get a burn line (unlike the pros, I have a pretty random assortment of kit and have got caught out)

Comment: Pretty sure the temperature has less to do with your risk of sunburn than UV index for the location, cloud cover, and time of year...

Comment: @AlexanderNied Sweating in hot weather washes off the suncream though.

Comment: @AlexanderNied The point is that if the temperature is 15, 20, or even 25°C, then shielding from the sun is pretty easy: just wear a long-sleeved known-SPF jersey (along with longer "shorts"). But the warmer it gets, the harder it is to cover up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Good information [Here](https://www.skincancer.org/skin-cancer-prevention/sun-protection/sun-protective-clothing/) and [Here](https://www.bicycling.com/bikes-gear/g20032596/the-upf-gear-you-need-to-avoid-sunburns-while-riding/)

While I would reapply at least once on a long ride, for most people a high quality high (50+) UPV sunscreen designed for sports and water use  should last all day on a cycle (This is my personal experience, most recommendations from health authorities are 2 hours between reapplication). Personally I find ones sold for kids use at the beach are the best, as they tend to be formulated to stay on in preference to smelling nice or not being greasy.

Its not like at the beach where you are wiping you arms with a towel regularly. For those with very fair skin, or who have not built up a suntan from being outside, then extra protection is worth considering.

Generally darker clothing offers higher protection, but the material used makes a big difference. If its too thin, or stretched tightly, then the UPF can be much lower than you would expect.  Some materials absorb UV better than others. Cotton is fairly good, but clothing that specifically designed for cycling would be best, these usually come in high tech fabrics specifically for UV protection.

If you want, protective sleeves with UPF ratings are available as well

Where I live in New Zealand, UV levels are extremely high. I MTB and use a cheap light weight long sleeve cotton Tee in these conditions, as its not high tech with a UPV rating, I put sunscreen on as well just to be sure I am safe.

Do not forget your upper thighs (below the cycle shorts), face and neck protection.  Also your back, if using too thin shirt can get burnt.

Comment: To be more specific, the OP can look at the “arm screens” and “arm coolers” described in the Bicycling link. I’ve usually heard the latter term, but they are clearly synonyms.

Comment: Re: "_Generally darker clothing offers higher protection_" Interesting. That's the opposite of my intuition, but it is very plausible. 1- Darker clothing will absorb more heat and trigger sweating earlier, and/or 2- lighter clothing would itself glow from being irradiated, and some of that emitted radiation would be towards, not away from, the skin.

Comment: Yep, protecting the thighs is important.

Comment: One gotcha can be helmet vents - specially if you have short hair or a recent haircut..    I personally wear "arm warmers" which are actually white surgical leg compresses and work really well for keeping cool.  I even found some white arm warmers which are some technical fabric, and they are perceptibly cooler when the air is moving.

Comment: @Sam the "glow" you describe is fluorescence, and it went out of fashion after the 80s. What really happens is that with light fabrics the light just scatters in every direction, including through the fabric. With dark fabric or dark skin for that matter the dark pigment absorbs more of the energy.

Comment: @Criggie Another item regularly offered is a cute little hat reminiscent of those that might have been worn in 1930s races. I've been able to do without their visor because my current helmet has a visor, but the purpose of these hats is then not just to wick sweat, but also to act as a sun shield, especially for those wearing helmets with large vents; is that right?

Comment: @mattnz Very nice pointers and thoughts, except that wearing cotton against the skin is very problematic if/when one starts to sweat. The cotton feels like a wet towel (that remains wet) chaffing the skin. The extra ventilation on forearms (compared, say, to one's back) possibly means that the water in cotton on the forearms would evaporate faster. Still, that preludes going out when there is any chance of rain.

Comment: @ojs But then when two colors (white, black) are available of the same arm sleeves, they should be labeled as having different SPFs. It's just that the maximum that can be specified on clothing is 50 SPF, and both colors exceed that maximum; is that right?

Comment: @Sam Correct, caps ("casquette") predate helmets by a lot, but yes they work well for sun blocking and acting as a visor/brim/peak for road-bikecycling, where your head is down more than a MTB or upright bike.

Comment: A slightly different take from somewhere with the opposite latitude and less UV: I use a reasonable factor 30-50 sunscreen, but not a sports-specific one.  At some point during the day I reapply, when stopped anyway, from a small container (a sachet holding about 3 or 4 applications) that stays in my riding kit.  This is beneficial because it allows me to deal with missed areas if they start to burn, or to supply a friend in need - we often end up with days that are forecast to be cloudy but turn out sunny.

Comment: @Sam generally "50+" is the maximum SPF and they don't bother to measure beyond that. It could also be that the white version has some pigment that absorbs UV and lets visible light scatter from the fabric.

Comment: @Criggie Terribly silly question, but one that needs to be asked (and surely not as an independent question). Are casquettes washable? If the firm front part requires handwashing or only a simple rinsing, that would be quite a pain.

Comment: I'm also from NZ and mountain bike, although currently living in Canada. I wear long sleeve merino jerseys for riding. I don't like the feel of sunscreen so choose to cover up instead. I find a thin merino material to be the best for riding in, it's light, thin, breathable, sweat wicking and provides a reasonable level of UV protection. I wear Mons Royale tops who claim to have a UV rating between 35-50 depending a thickness.

Comment: @sam yes they're washable - they're essentially a baseball cap but with a different  thinner brim shape and slightly lighter construction.  I'd wash them as often as gloves, so not every day, perhaps weekly depending on usage.  Pick up a couple cheap ones from aliexpress and see how they suit you, rather than buying a spendy one.

Comment: @Sam (and Criggie) I've had cheap (event souvenir) baseball caps with cardboard in the brim so not washable, but all cycling caps  I've come across have been washable.  I rarely wear them but my club one goes through the washing machine, or gets rinsed out in whatever is available (including once in a shower along with the rest of my kit).

Answer (score 4):

There are arm and leg "coolers" that will have UPF ratings (UPF is the clothing equivalent of SPF), and lightweight long-sleeved jerseys as well. They're all polyester/lycra or polyamide/lycra, as far as I can tell, as is a lot of cycling gear (apparently nylon/lycra is not effective as a sunblock, and is also hygroscopic, which leads to its faster deterioration). Lennard Zinn touched on this a bit in a [column](https://www.velonews.com/gear/tech-wearables/technical-faq-indoor-cycling-saddle-woes-outdoor-protective-clothing/), echoing some of what mattnz said here.

I live in a hot climate and have switched entirely to long-sleeved jerseys. I get some tan-through, but it's considerably reduced. I use zinc-based sunblock on my face, and that has lasted through some long rides without reapplication, but it does lend a zombie-like pallor.

Comment: https://www.velofanatics.com/uv-sun-protection-cycling-clothing-guide/

Comment: +1 for Zinc based sunscreens. I find that they also don't get as greasy as the more prevalent sunblocks, which leads to better perspiration evaporation and more comfort. In my opinion, it's more than worth the zombie look.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget how quick the pro racers are.  Their exposure is far less, so they don't need to reapply sunscreen.

It's possible you burn very easily. It's also possible you're not using enough (it needs to go on quite thick), that you miss bits and burn in small areas, or that it gets rubbed away. I definitely overlap sunscreen  with my jersey sleeves and shorts legs, but if I burn, it's at those edges.  You can mitigate this: apply one dose of sunscreen first thing, before breakfast and before getting your rising gear on (or roll your shorts up and leave your jersey off).  Be sure to cover further than you think you need around the edges, including gloves, where I just cover the backs of my hands, and around any wristwatch.  When you're just about to depart, apply another lot of sunscreen.  You probably won't get as much to soak in, and it won't double the protection, but it will fill in any missing bits.  Letting the first dose soak in will protect against rubbing to some extent.

I did a [TdF mountain stage](https://www.strava.com/activities/1672382419) (turned into a 200km loop, and with a modified start). It was won by [Warren Barguil in 4:40](https://www.cyclingnews.com/races/tour-de-france-2017/stage-18/results/).  I was out for over 12 hours, or 11.5 hours discounting the descent the pros missed out on (they also missed out on a rather large pizza between the two massive climbs).  That's a factor of around 2.5.

I started with factor 50 applied at about 0730, and topped up in the early afternoon when I was stopped in some shade anyway.  That was fine, and I've got fairly pale skin to start with.

The pros do occasionally start with sleeves on.  Thin ones ("arm coolers", though I suspect the name is more derived from "arm warmers" than accurate) are available that provide decent sun protection, though I haven't used them personally.  With the right riding skills they can be taken off on a climb while riding with no hands; I've seen experienced riders do this.  These sleeves are made from  thin, close-fitting, and even fabric.  They don't have holes that would allow spots to burn, but instead wick the sweat to the surface where it evaporates quickly, providing almost as much cooling as if it evaporated directly on the skin.

You're right that arm warmers get horribly sweaty.  They're a useful stopgap when touring, as I found when I was surprised by how sunny it was in a notoriously rainy place, had no suncream with me, and got a little burnt.

Comment: I once had to use arm warmers after a sun burn as well. [Fleecy black Craft arm warmers](https://www.craftsports.us/products/unisex-craft-arm-warmer?variant=20151883989051) in 35°C midsummer sun. They are surprisingly cool once completely soaked in sweat. I imagined you could also intentionally soak them. You can easily roll them down to the wrists when you don’t need them without stopping.

Comment: @Michael they look quite similar to my Endura ones, except mine are water-repellent and block the wind fairly well.  A deliberate soaking would have been worth a try, but they felt dry on the outside while wet inside.  I have to stop briefly to roll mine down - or at least I did before a year of intermittent lockdowns shrank my biceps (and before that  a crash that put my left arm out of action for a while - coincidentally the day I wore the arm warmers as sunblock)

Answer (score 2):

There is now a company called Lumiton making sports apparel that converts the high-intensity sunlight in low-intensity red and near-infrared light.  This has the effect of keeping your skin cooler and removing all of the UV exposure.  There are also some health benefits to the red and NIR light in scientific studies.  If you aren't wanting to apply and re-apply sunscreen for your rides, this might be a good solution.

https://lumiton.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're in control of the time to go on a ride, the easiest way to avoid excessive sun exposure, yet ride during the safer daylight hours, is to determine the exact time for sunrise/sunset
([Canada](https://nrc.canada.ca/en/research-development/products-services/software-applications/sun-calculator/),
[U.S.](https://gml.noaa.gov/grad/solcalc/sunrise.html),
[sunrise-sunset](https://sunrise-sunset.org),
[timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/),
[almanac](https://www.almanac.com/astronomy/sun-rise-and-set),
[calculatorsoup](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/sunrise_sunset.php), ...) and to ride such that your ride starts at sunrise or ends at sunset, or shortly before/after.

A side benefit is that there are remarkably fewer cars on long stretches of country roads early on weekend mornings.

This adds a small complication. You might aim for the lightest clothing for an 8:30am-start group ride, but it may be too chilly at 5 or 6:00am to ride without an extra layer. That's a separate issue though.